# can we scrape data for a website which requires authentication in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

I am trying to `web scraping` using `node.js` for a website that requires authentication. Is there any way to perform this in `node.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer):

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://httpbin.org/forms/post');

    await page.type('input[name="custname"]', 'user');
    await page.type('input[name="custemail"]', 'user@example.com');

    await Promise.all([
      page.click('button'),
      page.waitForNavigation(),
    ]);

    await page.waitForSelector('pre');

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('pre').innerText;
    });

    console.log(JSON.parse(data).form.custemail);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

===============================
For the side from the comment:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    page.setDefaultTimeout(0);

    await page.goto('https://www.trxade.com/market/login');
    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="deaNumber"]');

    await page.type('input[name="deaNumber"]', '...');
    await page.type('input[name="password"]', '...');

    await Promise.all([
      page.click('input[name="form_login_proceed"]'),
      page.waitForNavigation(),
    ]);

    // await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I am getting: -   No node found for selector: input[name="nameOfAttribute"]

Comment: Can you provide the URL?

Comment: It seems you just need to wait for the form a bit. I've added the example in the answer.

Comment: I am getting the same issue again,'No node found for selector: input[name="deaNumber"]' . I can't understand that before 2-3 days, it was working fine but somehow it stopped again.

Comment: Maybe the site temporarily loads longer and timeout error happens? I've added `page.setDefaultTimeout(0);` to the last example to prevent timeout errors.

Comment: thanks for the reply but this syntax is also not working, the site is loading as normally as the previous time.

Comment: If you ran the `document.querySelector('input[name="deaNumber"]')` in the browser console of the used Chrome after the error is thrown, what is the result?